# Special price not displaying magento

Tags: magento

i'm usign magento 1.8.1 and my special price are not displaying on my custom theme. I have  activate default theme and the special price is still not displaying.

Can you help me?

Comment: how do you add your special price?

Comment: first all check, special price less than product price, also check the starting date and end date then do reindex and remove cache and try it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: The starting date is on august 8th. yeshansachithak what do you mean?

Comment: @BastienGalindo-fauré Do you add your special price using `Dashboard` or `coding`. That's I wanted to know. There have some few ways to add Special Prices in Magento.

Comment: do you use the good customer group ?

Comment: i had it on the product on my admin panel

Comment: @ Christophe Ferreboeuf the good customer group? i'm a novice on magento

Comment: @BastienGalindo-fauré I suggest you have to search from google or youtube this kind of things. There have lot of tutorials for those. I can give you some tips. You can assign a customer group, catalog price, promotion for one particular product.

Comment: On my view.phtml i can display it with '<?php echo $_product->getSpecialPrice()?>' but when i click on "add to cart" i have the regular price and not the special

Comment: I found the solution. It's a problem on my product. When i add a special price to another product it works